# How to set a widget in the NOX android emulator?

Tags: android, emulation

Is it possible to set a widget on the screen using the Nox Emulator (version 3.7.3.0)?
How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Of course, the long click on the background gives no result.

Answer (score 1):

Long click the screen where you want to add the widget. After a few seconds you should see the widgets icon at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I'm on Nox 6.0 and this isn't working for me. Is there a new way?